How to lock installed app in device using Flutter app
I want to know how to lock the app that is already installed on the device using Flutter. I have no idea how to do it. Although I log into phone device settings and disable that app, the user can manually enable it. I want to know how to do it and does is any flutter package for it.
I have already loaded the device installed app. When I click the toggle button, then should lock that app with a timer.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Application> _apps = [];
  List<bool> _apps_lock_Status = [];
  bool _isLoading = true;
  bool light = true;
  int index = 0;
  String _key = "key";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchApps();
    get_data();
  }

  void get_data() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<dynamic> dynamicList = jsonDecode(prefs.getString(_key)!);
    _apps_lock_Status = dynamicList.map((item) => item as bool).toList();
  }

  void save_data() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(_key, json.encode(_apps_lock_Status));
  }

  void _fetchApps() async {
    List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
        onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
        includeAppIcons: true,
        includeSystemApps: true);

    for (Application a in apps) {
      _apps_lock_Status.add(false);
    }

    setState(() {
      _apps = apps;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'App Locker for Students',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('App Locker'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Table(
            children: _apps.map((app) {
              // Convert the app's icon to an Image
              Widget appIcon;
              int index = _apps.indexOf(app);
              if (app is ApplicationWithIcon) {
                appIcon = Image.memory(
                  app.icon,
                  width: 2, // Set icon size
                  height: 40,
                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, // Fit the icon properly
                );
              } else {
                appIcon = const Icon(Icons.broken_image); // Fallback if no icon
              }

              // Create a new TableRow for each app in the _apps list
              return TableRow(children: [
                appIcon, // A random icon, you can change it
                Text(app.appName), // App name
                Switch(
                  value: _apps_lock_Status[index],
                  activeColor: Colors.red,
                  onChanged: (bool value) {
                    setState(() {
                      // Update your local state
                      _apps_lock_Status[index] = value;
                      save_data();

                      if (value) {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "App locked");
                      } else {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "App unlocked");
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ]);
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


